# Seeking Spain Districts shapefile?

Tags: data, spain

Does anyone know a source of districts in Spain?

I can find Madrid and Barcelona each at a different site. If I try to collect the districts for the whole country it would be a massive undertaking.

Is there any central information site with these? or does anybody has this shapefile?

Comment: [@David Vaz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/128887/david-vaz), would you be satisfied with such quality [Geofabrik OpenStreetMap shapefiles for Spain](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/spain-latest-free.shp.zip)?

Comment: If it is open data that you seek an alternative place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: A source I like to use for this that is quick and easy can be found here http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Comment: Alternatively, I can suggest [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown), [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/), [European Environment Agency(EEA)](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/folder_listing).

Comment: The closest answer was from @AWGIS , unfortunately, it only goes as far as municipalities, and I really need districts. Administrative boundaries should be easier to find...

Comment: Have you tried [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html)?

Comment: This is not free, but data is very well organized for immediate use in GIS https://data.nextgis.com/en/ I'm developer at NextGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this site you can download all the admin levels shapefile http://www.ine.es/censos2011_datos/cen11_datos_resultados_seccen.htm

If you dissolve the geometries by field CUDIS you have the grometries of districts.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a newer site for this answer:

https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/?sort=modified&q=spain

There you can find and export the boundaries of any admin levels of spain or other countries.

cheers.

Comment: This looks very promising. However, are municipalities the lowest administrative level that can be found? It would be nice to have also cities, towns, etc.